# jqgrid error Status: 'error'. Error code: 500 on add

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Ok, I know there are already questions on here about this but none are giving me an answer.

I'm using jqgrid in MVC. In my View I have set up a jqgrid:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var invoiceId = @Model.Invoice.InvoiceId;
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Invoice/InvoiceLineGridData/' + invoiceId,

....
            editurl: '/Invoice/SaveInvoiceLine/' + invoiceId,

...
        });
```

So my jqgrid is a list of `invoiceLines` that relate to an `invoice`. The edit works fine but when I try to do an add I get  error Status: 'error'. Error code: 500.

The method it's calling on the controller is like:

```
public void SaveInvoiceLine(InvoiceLine invoiceLine, int id)
        {
            ...
        }
```

So what's causing the error on the add is it's trying to assign a `null` to `id`. I don't want to make the id nullable because it never will (should) be.

I've found the issue isn't with: `var invoiceId = @Model.Invoice.InvoiceId;`

as I for an experiment changed to  `editurl: '/Invoice/SaveInvoiceLine/2',`

Even with this hardcoded on add I'm still getting the error with it coming through nullable.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This did it:

http://blog.palelocust.com/?p=52

Comment: Hello! Link break.